# Can we initialize memory to 0 for newly allocated memory generated by realloc?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I am allocating 4 bytes of memory using `calloc`.
Now i need more 4 bytes, So i use `realloc`. But for newly allocated memory block of 4 bytes i need to initialize the memory to 0

Comment: `memset` would be one way - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html `memset(p+4, 0, 4)`

Comment: C or C++, please pick one.

Comment: If `C++` you should not be using `malloc` and friends.